# CSV Grouping w/o Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.x

Id like to group data in a `.csv` file. My data is like the following:

```
code,balance
CN,999.99
CN,1.01
LS,177.77
LS,69.42
LA,200.43
WO,100
```

I would like to group the items by code and sum up the balances of the like codes. Desired output would be:

```
code,blance
CN,1001
LS,247.19
...
```

I was originaly using `Pandas` for this task but will not have a package available to put that library on a server.

```
mydata = pd.read_csv('./tmp/temp.csv')
out = mydata.groupby('code').sum()
```

Solutions would preferably be compatible with `Python 2.6`.
I apologize if this is a duplicate, the other posts seem to be grouping differently.

I would also like to avoid doing this in a -

```
if code = x
    add balance to x_total
```

-kind of way

**MY SOLUTION:**

```
def groupit():
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    with open('tmp.csv') as fd:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fd)
        for row in reader:
            groups[row['code']].append(float(row['balance.']))
    total={key:sum(groups[key]) for key in groups}
    total=str(total)
    total=total.replace(' ','')
    total=total.replace('{','')
    total=total.replace('}','')
    total=total.replace("'",'')
    total=total.replace(',','\n')
    total=total.replace(':',',')

    outfile = open('out.csv','w+')
    outfile.write('code,balance\n')
    outfile.write(total)
```

Comment: What format have you read your data into? What have you tried so far with that?

Comment: Added py2.6 compatible version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Python > 2.6:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

groups = defaultdict(list)
with open('text.txt') as fd:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fd)
    for row in reader:
        groups[row['code']].append(float(row['balance']))

totals = {key: sum(groups[key]) for key in groups}
print(totals)
```

This outputs:

```
{'CN': 1001.0, 'LS': 247.19, 'LA': 200.43, 'WO': 100.0}
```

## Python = 2.6:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

groups = defaultdict(list)
with open('text.txt') as fd:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fd)
    for row in reader:
        groups[row['code']].append(float(row['balance']))

totals = dict((key, sum(groups[key])) for key in groups)
print(totals)
```

Comment: thank you for both solutions. The first was more than enough I had made a mistake on my end. As a side question, can you help me understand why my `codes` with `totals` are printed in a different order than the code are in the in-file?

Comment: Sure. `defaultdict` and `dict` do not preserve order. To preserve order you can user an `OrderedDict` from  `collections` library.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
with open("data.csv", 'r') as f:
data = f.readlines()

result = {}
for val in range(1, len(data)-1):
    x = data[val].split(",")
    if x[0] not in result:
        result[x[0]] = float(x[1].replace('\n', ""))
    else:
        result[x[0]] = result[x[0]] + float(x[1].replace('\n', ""))
```

`result` dictionary will have the values of interest which can then be saves as csv.

```
import csv

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, result.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(result)
```

Hope this helps :)